# How to use BigQuery SQL syntax to get value as the key in an JSON output

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a table similar to the following:

| Region | Country | Exports |
| --- | --- | --- |
| North America | US | Tech |
| North America | US | Vehicles |
| North America | US | Food |
| North America | Canada | Tech |
| North America | Canada | Food |
| North America | Canada | Tourism |

I am able to get an aggregated output using the following syntax:

`select region, struct(country, array_agg(distinct(exports))) from exports_table group by region, country`

which looks like:

```
[
  {
    "f0_": {
      "region": "North America",
      "_field_2": {
        "country": "US",
        "_field_2": [
          "Tech",
          "Vehicles",
          "Food",
          ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "f0_": {
      "region": "North America",
      "_field_2": {
        "country": "Canada",
        "_field_2": [
          "Tech",
          "Food",
          "Tourism",
          ]
      }
    }
  },

]
```

How can I translate this structure 1. to use the **fields** as **keys** and 2. **better aggregation** (as below)? (This is something doable on MySQL using `JSON_OBJECTAGG` and `JSON_ARRAYAGG`)

```
[
    {
        "North America": {
            "US": ["Tech","Vehicles","Food"],
            "Canada": ["Tech","Vehicles","Food"]
        }

    }
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select format('[{"%s": {%s}}]', Region, string_agg(CountryExports)) as output
from (
  select Region, 
    format('"%s": %s', Country, format('%T', array_agg(Exports))) CountryExports
  from exports_table
  group by Region, Country
)
group by Region
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Should be easy to apply above approach to whatever your real use case is

Comment: Have you tried? Did it work for you?